# Word chart data updates in workbook but Word does not refresh the chart

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I have a Word document (.docx) that has a series of charts. My code successfully updates the values behind a pie chart and Word appropriately displays the results (refreshes the front end of the chart, whatever you would like to call it).

The same sadly cannot be said for a clustered bar chart. The values in the workbook update but the front end does not refresh to display the new values.

Once I right click on the chart and select Edit Data (I do not even have to edit anything, just close the workbook window when it opens) it then refreshes the displayed values on the chart.

Is there someway I can force a refresh of the front end without going through that? Closing the file and re-opening has no effect.

What I have:

```
wordcon.Application wordapp = new wordcon.Application();
wordcon.Document docx = new wordcon.Document();

wordapp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[2].Chart.ChartData.Activate();

excelcon.Workbook excelwb = wordapp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[2].Chart.ChartData.Workbook;
excelcon.Worksheet excelws = excelwb.Worksheets[1];

excelws.Cells[1, 2] = reference.top_issues_1_name;

excelws.Cells[6, 1] = "a";
excelws.Cells[6, 2] = reference.top_issues_1;

excelws.Cells[5, 1] = "b";
excelws.Cells[5, 2] = reference.top_issues_2;

excelws.Cells[4, 1] = "c";
excelws.Cells[4, 2] = reference.top_issues_3;

excelws.Cells[3, 1] = "d";
excelws.Cells[3, 2] = reference.top_issues_4;

excelws.Cells[2, 1] = "e";
excelws.Cells[2, 2] = reference.top_issues_5;

excelwb.Close();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelws);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelwb);

docx.SaveAs2(reference.chart_file_forked_path + reference.chart_file_forked_file_name);

wordapp.Quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docx);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordapp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to this in Powerpoint. I suspect the solution will be similar.

**Untested**

Let me know if this doesn't work in Word and I will revise.

```
Dim cObj as Shape  'Shape container for the ChartObject

'Set cObj = '

    '## Expose the data sheet'
    cObj.Chart.chartData.Activate  

    '## Minimize it'
    cObj.Chart.chartData.Workbook.Application.WindowState = -4140  

'## code to manipulate the cObj, if any.'

'## when done, close the ChartData'

    '## When you're done, close the chartData'
    cObj.Chart.chartData.Workbook.Close
```

Comment: Hello David, take a look at my code I just added to my question. I believe I am essentially doing what you've posted, please correct if me if I am wrong on that.

Comment: I am not a C# guy but that *looks* right to my untrained eye..., but is it still not properly refreshing the data in the chart?

Comment: Or perhaps try something as simple as `wordapp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[2].Chart.Refresh`

Comment: That did it, I had drilled down too far and missed that one. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I'm running to 'touch' the word doc and force a refresh of an embedded excel chart (I'm using OpenXml library):

```
    //open word doc   
     using (var wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(someDocFileInfo.FullName, true))          
    {
       //open embedded excel object with chart
       var stream = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.EmbeddedPackageParts.First().GetStream();

       using (var ssDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
       {
           var wbPart = ssDoc.WorkbookPart;
           var sheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "Sheet1");
           if (sheet != null)
           {
               var ws = (wbPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart).Worksheet;
              //change the data in the excel sheet
              var cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("A", 2, ws);
              cell.CellValue = new CellValue("42");
              cell.DataType = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
               ws.Save();
           }   
       }

       //now 'touch' the word doc to refresh the chart
       var settingPart = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType<DocumentSettingsPart>().First();
       var updateFields = new UpdateFieldsOnOpen();
       updateFields.Val = new OnOffValue(true);
       settingPart.Settings.PrependChild<UpdateFieldsOnOpen>(updateFields);
       settingPart.Settings.Save();
       }
    }
```